# Google drive api sharingRateLimitExceeded error , when trying to change a drive file using the google permissions api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Getting **sharingRateLimitExceeded** when using google drive permissions api. according to the docs this can be related to 'email limit' . but I am using '**sendNotificationEmail**' , that seems to be ignored, as when the api does work a mail is sent to the user. the permission created is "**writer**".

Also it is not clear to me what the limitation are, are they per api key ? or per user ? and what are the actual limits ?

This is my code:

```
         function createRequest(account) {
            var request = gapi.client.request({
                'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '/permissions',
                'method': 'POST',
                'headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                'body': {
                    'role': 'reader',
                    'type': 'user',
                    'sendNotificationEmail': false,
                    'emailAddress': account
                }
            });

            return request;
        }

        var batch = gapi.client.newBatch();

        accounts.forEach(function (account) {
            var req = createRequest(account);
            batch.add(req);
        })


        batch.execute(function (jsonResp) {
            console.log(jsonResp);
        })
```

Comment: how many permissions updates are you doing and over what period of time?

Comment: How many updates as the same Google user or with the same api key?

Comment: both. Your question is about rate limit, but you have provided no information about the rate you are sending at.

Comment: Our solution is a saas app, and I currently dont know the rate that is used globally on our api key, but for a specific user, I am seeing sharingRateLimitExceeded, even after a few api calls  in several minutes ( seems random ) , that is why I am asking if the rate is per user/ per api key , and what is the rate

Comment: there are multiple rate limits that you could be exceeding. That's why I asked what rate you are submitting at.

Comment: In the google api console I can see that my global Quotas status for google drive is
Queries per 100 seconds -  current usage : 0.015  , Limit 10,000. Queries per day - current usage : 8 , Limit 1,000,000,000

Comment: Which API are you using? How are you using it? What is triggering it? You probably have some fault(s) in your implementation. If you can't tell us/show us maybe you should ask it on Super User or Server Fault?

Comment: added my implementation code in the question